# Live save pictures to server in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want the app to record video or take photos at 30 fps and save them under one name on the server so that one photo changes and thus becomes a video. I already found the code that makes the server. I spent the whole day looking for an answer to my question and couldn't find anything, so I decided to ask. This should work as an [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en_GB&gl=US) application. Can this be done at all? Thanks for any help.

**Code to make a server:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    EditText welcomeMsg;
    TextView infoIp;
    TextView infoMsg;
    String msgLog = "";

    ServerSocket httpServerSocket;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        welcomeMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.welcomemsg);
        infoIp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
        infoMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);

        infoIp.setText(getIpAddress() + ":"
                + HttpServerThread.HttpServerPORT + "\n");

        HttpServerThread httpServerThread = new HttpServerThread();
        httpServerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (httpServerSocket != null) {
            try {
                httpServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                        .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
                                + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }

        return ip;
    }

    private class HttpServerThread extends Thread {

        static final int HttpServerPORT = 8888;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                httpServerSocket = new ServerSocket(HttpServerPORT);

                while(true){
                    socket = httpServerSocket.accept();

                    HttpResponseThread httpResponseThread =
                            new HttpResponseThread(
                                    socket,
                                    welcomeMsg.getText().toString());
                    httpResponseThread.start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }

    private class HttpResponseThread extends Thread {

        Socket socket;
        String h1;

        HttpResponseThread(Socket socket, String msg){
            this.socket = socket;
            h1 = msg;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader is;
            PrintWriter os;
            String request;


            try {
                is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                request = is.readLine();

                os = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                String response =
                        "<html><head></head>" +
                                "<body>" +
                                "<h1>" + h1 + "</h1>" +
                                "</body></html>";

                os.print("HTTP/1.0 200" + "\r\n");
                os.print("Content type: text/html" + "\r\n");
                os.print("Content length: " + response.length() + "\r\n");
                os.print("\r\n");
                os.print(response + "\r\n");
                os.flush();
                socket.close();


                msgLog += "Request of " + request
                        + " from " + socket.getInetAddress().toString() + "\n";
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        infoMsg.setText(msgLog);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you will program two Android apps. A server and a client. The client will send data to the server. For instance a picture that the server has to store to file. What exactly are your problems?

Comment: @blackapps I want the program to quickly take photos and instantly send them to the server. The problem is that I can't write a client that will display those photos as video in the program and save them to the server, because I can't find the code to do it.

Comment: A client that will display something in the program. Which program? Please talk about server or talk about client as i do not understand what you mean with the program. You have two apps. Two programs.

Comment: @blackapps I have an application that makes a server and this same application should take photos and send them to this server. I want my app to work as an IP Webcam

Comment: Then it would send it to itself as you have only one application then. No need for a client or a server.

Comment: `I have an application that makes a server` ? That is a server. How would it make a server? Pretty unclear. Sigh... What exactly do you want?

Comment: @blackapps I have shown the code in the question with which I make the server

Comment: Yes. And the app that makes that server should also take pbotos and send them to this server,? Why?  Makes no sense to me as the app is the server and the server is the app.